# Global horizontal alignement in nested latex itemize environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

the next MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Running text
\begin{itemize}
  \item First level item
  \par\noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
bla bla bla
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Second level item
    \par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
bla bla bla
    \end{minipage}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
Running text
\end{document}
```

gives this output

```
Running text
  • First level item
    bla bla bla
    — Second level item
      bla bla bla
Running text
```

How can I obtain next output, 'bla bla bla' being aligned with 'Running text' :

```
Running text
  • First level item
bla bla bla
    — Second level item
bla bla bla
Running text
```

With `\labelwidth` and `\labelsep` I can align the first 'bla bla bla' but not the second one.

TIA

Comment: what about `\leftmargin`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the bla bla is not part of the list, why don't you end it first?

Comment: The bla bla bla _is_ indeed part of the list and contains material like tables and images that really must be as wide as possible, whatever depth the item is. This is why I need `\textwidth` and not `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with basic tools:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Running text
\begin{itemize}
  \item First level item
  \par\noindent
 \hspace{\linewidth-\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
bla bla bla
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Second level item
    \par\noindent
\hspace{\linewidth-\textwidth}%
```

[image] \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    bla bla bla
        \end{minipage}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

```
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A problem is that it is based on the nesting level. I used `\hspace{\dimexpr\linewidth-\columnwidth}` instead of `\hspace{-\dimexpr\leftmargini + \leftmarginii}`, which does not depend on the nesting level. A `\providecommand{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}` was given to support `multicol.sty`.

Comment: You didn't mention you were in a multicolumn environment. Could you post a code with you real code?

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS no need for the `\providecommand`, `\columnwidth` is always defined, even in 1-column mode. also I think you are looking for `\@totalleftmargin`

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS: I have modified my answer with a simpler code, not depending on the nesting level.

Comment: @Bernard  in order to be able to typeset both in one column or many columns mode, you may change any occurrence of `\textwidth` to `\columnwidth`

Comment: Sure, but you question doesn't mention this point, so I gave a code  for a single column document.